# How to stroke the same layer across multiple layers

Tags: gimp

In gimp, I have about 98 layers. I have a path that I would like to stroke on across all the layers. Is there a way to do this without individually going through each layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that easily using the Python console. I have a couple answers around  with longer or shorter hints on how to use it -this is one: https://superuser.com/questions/1067478/how-to-change-several-images-in-gimp-that-are-already-open/1067867?noredirect=1

In this case, after having made a call to `gimp.image_list()` and selecting your target image in that list, assigning it to a `image` variable, just do a call to `pdb.gimp_edit_stroke_vectors(...)` for each layer on the images.

Therefore, your whole `filters->Python-fu->Console` sessions might be something along:

```
image = gimp.image_list()[0]
for layer in image.layers:
    pdb.gimp_edit_stroke_vectors(layer, image.vectors[0])
```

(if your image is the last one openned (then its position on the image_list will be '0' )  and if your path is the topmost one on the paths dialog (which also will have '0' as an index).
You can use calls to `pdb.gimp_context_set_foreground` (or ...set_brush, and ...set_dynamics, ..set_brush_size)  inside the for loop to change the respective settings as you progress through the layers, although there is no call to change the active tool. Use the "browse"  button on the bottom of the Python console dialog to learn about all possible calls.

Comment: A follow up question to the original. When I use this method, it uses whatever tool has been highlighted. Were I to do this using the gui, I utually get to select the stroke style. I want to stroke a dense dotted line of width 6. How do I use python-fu to get this? My current lines of code are along what you suggested: 
>>>image = gimp.image_list()[0]
>>> for layer in image.layers:
...  pdb.gimp_edit_stroke_vectors(layer, image.vectors[0])

Comment: Currently, there is no call in the PDB for the non-painting-tool version of vector or selection stroke. The workaround is to craft a brush and spacing that will work for you, and select the "follow direction" painting dynamic.

Comment: I just used the spacing feature to get the dotted line.